# How to solve: Unable to locate virtual box guest additions?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to install virtual box guest addition on my Debian VM. But I am unable to do so. I have a **macOS Mojave** as host and I can't seem to install it no matter what.

Below is a picture of the error which occurs:
[image]

I feel extremely lost and I can't figure it out where the problem lies. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238837

Comment: I am trying to install guest additions on Debian which is on my VM, not macOS.

Comment: Then download the ISO, and point your VM's "CD" to it; is there a problem with that? -> https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-linux   (Debian ==> Ubuntu might work)

Answer (score 0):

From the image (thanks for the image), the drive is locked. What you should do is double check the program installaition path first, then check the guest additions cd image path. Afterwards you should do is try to change it back to the path in the image, then it might work.